# calling a php file delete function from a java script

Tags: javascript

I have my php function that deletes a file from server on user button click. this function is called from a javascript that redirects to previous page on same button click.. I tried this  but its not working. 
the page redirects but the file doesn't get deleted from server. And if i remove the 'return false', the file gets deleted but redirect fails. Any clue pls

my javascript function goes like this :

```
function goBack() {
  var x = confirm('Do you start afresh?');
  if (x == true) {
    <?php echo deleteimage(); ?>;

    window.location.href = "<?php echo $_SESSION['ref'] ?>";
  }
  return false;
}
```

And my php function goes thus:

```
 <?php
function deleteimage(){
  if(isset($_POST['backbtn'])) {
    @unlink($_SESSION['imgname']);
  }
}
?>
```

And I have my html form submit button as :

```
<input name="backbtn" type="submit" value="Back" onclick="return goBack();"
```

Comment: You can't call a php function from a javascript function.  You have to send a request to the server and have that trigger the php function.

Comment: As above, you can't call php from js. Also, you'd want to wait (the request to the server is asynchronous) until the delete has happened and only then do the redirect. Otherwise, what would you do when it fails?

Comment: Thanks guys! Now i created a redirect.php with my php file delete codes and a (header:Location) in there. Everything works now.My problem now is to trigger a confirm dialogbox that will only delete file when user clicks ok , else nothing happens to the uploaded file. i cant figure out how to do that , my brain are already messed up :(

Comment: Never mind,  i have it all sorted out. :)